# idea fails to execute units tests due to initialization error

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

I have `gradle` project with unit tests. I want to execute and debug tests using Idea.

When I execute tests via gradle - it works fine.

But when I try run it using `idea` context menu (like `run XXXtest`) it fails with error

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: Field 'fTestClass' was not found in class org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.

    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getInternalState(WhiteboxImpl.java:581)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.getInternalState(Whitebox.java:308)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.testcaseworkaround.PowerMockJUnit4MethodValidator.validateTestMethods(PowerMockJUnit4MethodValidator.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.testcaseworkaround.PowerMockJUnit4MethodValidator.validateInstanceMethods(PowerMockJUnit4MethodValidator.java:67)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:51)
....
```

What is the problem? The dependencies in gradle show `powermock 1.6.2` and `junit 4.12`

Comment: When you run the tests through IntelliJ, are you forwarding the execution to Gradle or are you using the IDE itself?

Comment: I use IDE itself

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the project and cleanly re-importing? If it works in Gradle then it's a problem with IntelliJ setup.

Comment: I had a feeling that there was something wrong with project import as I had issues in the beginning, but later they kinda disappeared I'll try.

Comment: I did the re-import but the same issue remains

Comment: Is the issue reproduced with powermock 1.6.1 and IDEA? The issue looks related to: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/551

Comment: the problem is that my classpath (at least gradle classpath in the project) contains 1.6.2 and 4.12 so there shouldn't be issue.  maybe IDEA uses its own or something

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?